# React - Conditional mounting/unmounting of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

**Context**

Let's say I have page that displays a list of employees, along with many other buttons and components. and whenever I click on an employee, a side panel appears with a bunch of information about that employee. If I click on any other employee while an employee is selected, the side panel remains intact with only the information inside it being re-fetched and updated.
I can also, change the employee's information from that side panel by editing the different fields and clicking `Update` which bulk updates every updated fields.

**Problem Statement**

Whenever an employee's information is being edited, I can also click on another employee, which, of course, means that the edited data for the previous employee is lost.

**Objective**

What I need to do in this case is that, whenever an employee's information is being edited from the side panel (a flag is present to denote that), and if any other component/buttons apart from `Update` is clicked, then I need to show a modal which states that everything that is unsaved would be lost. If the user selects `Ok`, the component that was clicked should mount/rendered/perform whatever it does. Otherwise, the user should go back to the previous state.

---

I initially tried to achieve that by using `componentWillUnmount` of the sidepanel, but it didn't really work because that component will unmount anyway. What I am thinking is that, I need to put a `onClick` handler in every button/component now apart from that 'Update' which checks if any information is being edited, if yes it will render that component, if not it will render that modal, and the user decides what to do in that modal. I am very skeptic about this as well by placing checks everywhere for a minor thing.

Anyone with experience about related to this use case ? Any insights would be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

First Put `isEdited` state  `isEdited: false` Then when you edit the post then set `isEdited` to true. When user clicks `update` then set isEdited back to false. When user clicks button other than `update` then check `isEdited` if `isEdited` is `true` then dispay `modal with message and button` when button of model is click set `isEdited` to `false`.

Hopefully this will help

Comment: Hmmm. The problem is not displaying the modal but how to go back to previous state or render other button/components based on what the user clicks on tha modal.

Comment: If user clicks `cancel` on modal then sate remains same so there is nothing to do.If user clicks `ok` then perform your `api` call to fetch  data about other user. If user clicks other button  then `perform task of each button `

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways I can think to do this.

1. Add a check at the start of the function for each buttons onClick. As you've mentioned already, this is tedious, especially if there are lots of buttons that should affect the state.
2. Create a function that wraps the onClick functions, to perform this check. Similar to 1, however a bit easier to repeat:

```
const myOnClick = newEmployeeNumber => {
  myState.employeeToView = newEmployeeNumber;
}

const checkUserWantsToContinue = (onClickToRunWhenContinued) => {
  if (myAppState.isEdited) {
    promptUserToSaveFirst();
  } else {
    onClickToRunWhenContinued();
  }
}

return (
  <div onClick={checkUserWantsToContinue(myOnClick)} />
);
```

3. You mentioned that you are trying to put this into the componentWillUnmount function. That implies that *something* is making the component unmount. Can you add the check in there? So rather than checking with the user before the component unmounts, check with them before the *action that makes the component unmount*.